# Regular Expression How to find "unconsecutive suffix" in suffix

Tags: c#, regex

I have this document with many text rows which mixed with 2 languages and look like this: (look at the words עשמ and טקסט)

```
<a href="http://www.example.co.il/search/index.aspx?sQuery=ID:עשמ@111/13&CaseType=טקסט" />
```

**Target:**
What i'm trying to do is to replace the "Other Language" text part to encoded one.

**The Problem:**
I get only the first letter of the "Other Language" text.

I'm using this pattern of Regex:

```
((href=\"http://.+?sQuery=[^\"]*)([א-ת]+)([^\"]*\"))+?
```

This is the full code of the method:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test", "*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string file in files)
{
   string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)); 
   fileContent = fileContent.Replace("windows-1255", "utf-8");      
   Regex hrefRegex = new Regex("((href=\"http://.+?sQuery=[^\"]*)([א-ת]+)([^\"]*\"))+?");

   fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent,hrefRegex.ToString(), delegate(Match match)
   {
       string textToEncode = match.Groups[3].Value;
       string encodedText = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textToEncode, new UTF8 Encoding(false)).ToUpper();
       return match.Groups[2].Value + encodedText + match.Groups[4].Value;
   });          

File.WriteAllText(file + "_fix.html", fileContent, new UTF8Encoding(false));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

And how can i update my regex pattern so it will find the all "other languages" parts in the href, because for now i just bring the first one.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a problem with links with different kinds of browsers because of the other language and the Request that each browser generates.
It decodes to another Encode and I can't work with the text.

Comment: You can use `POST` with form data instead of using `GET` and passing parameters in `URL`

Comment: I know. But I can't because I need to save on the original structure of the html.
Those files comes from a libary that I'm working with.
And I think that search-engines not clicks on input[submit] elements,
So I'll loose the SEO thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just has one match, which is the whole string. If you want to translate char by char, you have to use this regex: `([א-ת])` and if you want to translate each word, use this one: `([א-ת]+)`.

EDIT: To just translate those chars in the href part, do this:

```
            fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, hrefRegex , delegate(Match match)
            {
                string textToEncode = match.ToString();
                textToEncode = Regex.Replace(textToEncode, "[א-ת]", delegate(Match smallMatch)
                {
                    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(smallMatch.ToString(), new UTF8 Encoding(false)).ToUpper();
                });
                return textToEncode;
            });
```

Comment: I want to translate only the text within the href text.
Not the all doc.